# Writing a correspondence between Oracle and XSD data types

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

My task is to create a conversion from Oracle metadata to XSD formatting to ensure correct translation of data from Oracle to XML.

To accomplish this I need to provide a correspondence table for the Oracle data types and XSD data types. The following is such a table for numbers. Right part of the expression is Oracle's Number datatype format, and the left one are the tags to be inserted into the "restriction" element of xs:decimal tag in XSD. Then the explanation goes.

**Number(null,null) <-> totalDigits=38** : *any 38 digits with/without decimal point*

**Number(4,2) <-> totalDigits=4; fractionDigits=2** : 
*any 4 digits with decimal point from a missing one to the one in the middle of 4 digits; but what about "1600" ? it matches XSD, but not sure its ok for Oracle's Number(4,2)*

**Number(4,0) <-> totalDigits=4;fractionDigits=0** : 
*integer with 4 digits*

(1) Is my understanding correct?
Could you provide me with a better match between Oracle and XSD numeric data types?

(2) Is there a built-in way to generate XSD from Oracle table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This restriction is not a good idea. The number type is defined as NUMBER(precision, scale), see examples in Table 2-2 in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm.
You have to generate regexp pattern for the restriction, e.g.:

NUMBER(4)   `"-?[0-9]{1,4}"`
NUMBER(4,2)   `"-?([0-9]{1,2})?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?"`
NUMBER(4,-2)   `"0|-?[0-9]{1,4}0{2}"`
NUMBER(2,-4)   `"0|-?[0-9]{1,2}0{4}"`
NUMBER(2,4)   `"0|-?0?\.0{2}[0-9]{1,2}"`

For NUMBER types with positive scale you can use combination of totalDigits, fractionDigits, minExclusive and maxExclusive.

NUMBER(4)   `totalDigits="4" fractionDigits="0"`
NUMBER(4,2)   `totalDigits="4" fractionDigits="2" minExclusive="-100" maxExclusive="100"`
NUMBER(2,4)   `totalDigits="4" fractionDigits="4" minExclusive="-.01" maxExclusive=".01"`

Comment: Pavel, could you please explain why I cannot use standart restriction tags for this?

Comment: @MiamiBeach with totalDigits=4; fractionDigits=2 the value 9999 matches the XSD but not the NUMBER(4,2) type, which says 4 digits with multiplicator 10^-2, so the max value is `99.99`.